# EXTJS 6: JS files not concatenating into one single app.js file

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

Sorry a newbie here.I have created a project.I build using

```
sencha app build classic
```

What I want is having all the production files in build folder and all js files to be concatenated into one single app.js file in build folder so that it reduces the size of my project to be deployed. But instead when I look in development console, the application is still accessing original js files from classic instead of from the build folder.
What I want is building should be able to create a development folder in build folder which should have al the files I need and I should be directly able to deploy it on server.Here is my app.json file

```
{
    "name": "****",/**
     * The version of the application.
     */
    "version": "1.0.0.0",/**
     * The relative path to the application's markup file (html, jsp, asp, etc.).
     */
    "indexHtmlPath": "index.html",/**
     * Comma-separated string with the paths of directories or files to search. Any classes
     * declared in these locations will be available in your class "requires" or in calls
     * to "Ext.require". The "app.dir" variable below is expanded to the path where the
     * application resides (the same folder in which this file is located).
     */
    "classpath": [
        "app",
        "${toolkit.name}/src"
    ],/**
     * Comma-separated string with the paths of directories or files to search. Any classes
     * declared in these locations will be automatically required and included in the build.
     * If any file defines an Ext JS override (using Ext.define with an "override" property),
     * that override will in fact only be included in the build if the target class specified
     * in the "override" property is also included.
     */
    "overrides": [
        "overrides",
        "${toolkit.name}/overrides"
    ],/**
     * The Sencha Framework for this application: "ext" or "touch".
     */
    "framework": "ext",/**
     * The list of required packages (with optional versions; default is "latest").
     *
     * For example,
     *
     *      "requires": [
     *          "charts"
     *      ]
     */
    "requires": [
        "font-awesome",
        "charts",
        "ux"
    ],/**
     * Fashion build configuration properties.
     */
    "fashion": {
        "inliner": {
            "enable": false
        }
    },/**
     * Sass configuration properties.
     */
    "sass": {
        "namespace": "zscore",/**
         * File used to save sass variables edited via Sencha Inspector. This file
         * will automatically be applied to the end of the scss build.
         *
         *      "save": "sass/save.scss"
         *
         *//**
         * Comma-separated list of files or folders containing extra Sass. These
         * files are automatically included in the Sass compilation. By default this
         * is just "etc/all.scss" to allow import directives to control the order
         * other files are included.
         *
         * All "etc" files are included at the top of the Sass compilation in their
         * dependency order:
         *
         *      +-------+---------+
         *      |       | base    |
         *      | theme +---------+
         *      |       | derived |
         *      +-------+---------+
         *      | packages        |  (in package dependency order)
         *      +-----------------+
         *      | application     |
         *      +-----------------+
         */
        "etc": [
            "sass/etc/all.scss",
            "${toolkit.name}/sass/etc/all.scss"
        ],/**
         * Comma-separated list of folders containing Sass variable definitions
         * files. These file can also define Sass mixins for use by components.
         *
         * All "var" files are included after "etc" files in the Sass compilation in
         * dependency order:
         *
         *      +-------+---------+
         *      |       | base    |
         *      | theme +---------+
         *      |       | derived |
         *      +-------+---------+
         *      | packages        |  (in package dependency order)
         *      +-----------------+
         *      | application     |
         *      +-----------------+
         *
         * The "sass/var/all.scss" file is always included at the start of the var
         * block before any files associated with JavaScript classes.
         */
        "var": [
            "sass/var/all.scss",
            "sass/var",
            "${toolkit.name}/sass/var"
        ],/**
         * Comma-separated list of folders containing Sass rule files.
         *
         * All "src" files are included after "var" files in the Sass compilation in
         * dependency order (the same order as "etc"):
         *
         *      +-------+---------+
         *      |       | base    |
         *      | theme +---------+
         *      |       | derived |
         *      +-------+---------+
         *      | packages        |  (in package dependency order)
         *      +-----------------+
         *      | application     |
         *      +-----------------+
         */
        "src": [
            "sass/src",
            "${toolkit.name}/sass/src"
        ]
    },/**
     * List of all JavaScript assets in the right execution order.
     *
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *
     *      {
     *          // Path to file. If the file is local this must be a relative path from
     *          // this app.json file.
     *          //
     *          "path": "path/to/script.js",   // REQUIRED
     *
     *          // Set to true on one file to indicate that it should become the container
     *          // for the concatenated classes.
     *          //
     *          "bundle": false,    // OPTIONAL
     *
     *          // Set to true to include this file in the concatenated classes.
     *          //
     *          "includeInBundle": false,  // OPTIONAL
     *
     *          // Specify as true if this file is remote and should not be copied into the
     *          // build folder. Defaults to false for a local file which will be copied.
     *          //
     *          "remote": false,    // OPTIONAL
     *
     *          // If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and cached inside
     *          // localStorage until this value is changed. You can specify:
     *          //
     *          //   - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *          //   - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *          //
     *          "update": "",        // OPTIONAL
     *
     *          // A value of true indicates that is a development mode only dependency.
     *          // These files will not be copied into the build directory or referenced
     *          // in the generate app.json manifest for the micro loader.
     *          //
     *          "bootstrap": false   // OPTIONAL
     *      }
     *
     */
    "js": [
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true
        },
        {
            "path": "packages/sha1.js"
        }

    ],/**
     * Settings specific to classic toolkit builds.
     */
    "classic": {
        "js": [
            {
                "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl.js"
            }
        ]
    },/**
     * Settings specific to modern toolkit builds.
     */
    "modern": {
        "js": [
            {
                "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-modern-all-debug.js"
            }
        ]
    },/**
     * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
     *
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *
     *      {
     *          // Path to file. If the file is local this must be a relative path from
     *          // this app.json file.
     *          //
     *          "path": "path/to/stylesheet.css",   // REQUIRED
     *
     *          // Specify as true if this file is remote and should not be copied into the
     *          // build folder. Defaults to false for a local file which will be copied.
     *          //
     *          "remote": false,    // OPTIONAL
     *
     *          // If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and cached inside
     *          // localStorage until this value is changed. You can specify:
     *          //
     *          //   - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *          //   - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *          //
     *          "update": ""      // OPTIONAL
     *      }
     */
    "css": [
        {
            "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
            "bundle": true,
            "exclude": [
                "fashion"
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "resources/senchaicons.css",
            "remote": true
        },
        {
            "path": "resources/style.css",
            "remote": true
        }
    ],/**
     * This option is used to configure the dynamic loader. At present these options
     * are supported.
     *
     */
    "loader": {
        "cache": true,// When "cache" is not true, this value is the request parameter used// to control caching.//
        "cacheParam": "_dc"
    },/**
     * Settings specific to production builds.
     */
    "production": {
        "output": {
            "appCache": {
                "enable": true,
                "path": "cache.appcache"
            }
        },
        "loader": {
            "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
        },
        "cache": {
            "enable": true
        },
        "compressor": {
            "type": "yui"
        }
    },/**
     * Settings specific to testing builds.
     */
    "testing": {

    },/**
     * Settings specific to development builds.
     */
    "development": {
        "tags": []
    },/**
     * Controls the output structure of development-mode (bootstrap) artifacts. May
     * be specified by a string:
     *
     *      "bootstrap": "${app.dir}"
     *
     * This will adjust the base path for all bootstrap objects, or expanded into object
     * form:
     *
     *      "bootstrap": {
     *          "base": "${app.dir},
     *          "manifest": "bootstrap.json",
     *          "microloader": "bootstrap.js",
     *          "css": "bootstrap.css"
     *      }
     *
     * You can optionally exclude entries from the manifest. For example, to exclude
     * the "loadOrder" (to help development load approximate a build) you can add:
     *
     *      "bootstrap": {
     *          "manifest": {
     *              "path": "bootstrap.json",
     *              "exclude": "loadOrder"
     *          }
     *      }
     *
     */
    "bootstrap": {
        "base": "${app.dir}",
        "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
        "microloader": "bootstrap.js",
        "css": "bootstrap.css"
    },/**
     * Controls the output directory for build resources.  May be set with
     * either a string:
     *
     *      "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}"
     *
     * or an object containing values for various types of build artifacts:
     *
     *      {
     *          "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
     *          "page": {
     *              "path": "../index.html",
     *              "enable": false
     *          },
     *          "css": "${app.output.resources}/${app.name}-all.css",
     *          "js": "app.js",
     *          "microloader": {
     *              "path": "microloader.js",
     *              "embed": true,
     *              "enable": true
     *          },
     *          "manifest": {
     *              "path": "app.json",
     *              "embed": false,
     *              "enable": "${app.output.microloader.enable}"
     *          },
     *          "resources": "resources",
     *          "slicer": {
     *              "path": "${app.output.resources}/images",
     *              "enable": false
     *          },
     *          // Setting the "enable" property of this object to a Truthy value will cause a Application Cache
     *          // manifest file to be generated based on this files appCache object. This file will then be injected
     *          // into the index.html file of the built application
     *          "appCache":{
     *              "enable": false"
     *          }
     *      }
     *
     */
    "output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
        "page": "index.html",
        "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
        "js": "${build.id}/app.js",
        "appCache": {
            "enable": true
        },
        "resources": {
            "path": "${build.id}/resources",
            "shared": "resources"
        }
    },/**
    * Controls for localStorage caching
    *   "cache": {
    *       // This property controls whether localStorage caching of this manifest file is on or off.
    *       // if disabled no deltas will be generated during a build and full updates will be disabled
    *       "enable": false,
    *
    *       // This property allows for global toggle of deltas.
    *       // If set to a string the value will be used as the path to where deltas will be generated relative to you build.
    *       // If set to a Truthy Value the default path ok "deltas" will be used
    *       // If set to a Falsey value or if this property is not present deltas will be disabled and not generated.
    *
    *       "deltas": "deltas"
    *   }
    */
    "cache": {
        "enable": false,
        "deltas": "${build.id}/deltas"
    },/**
     * Used to automatically generate cache.manifest (HTML 5 application cache manifest)
     * file when you build.
     */
    "appCache": {
        "cache": [
            "index.html"
        ],/**
         * List of items in the NETWORK section
         */
        "network": [
            "*"
        ],/**
         * List of items in the FALLBACK section
         */
        "fallback": []
    },/**
     * Extra resources to be copied into the resource folder as specified in the "resources"
     * property of the "output" object. Folders specified in this list will be deeply copied.
     */
    "resources": [
        {
            "path": "resources",
            "output": "shared"
        },
        {
            "path": "${toolkit.name}/resources"
        },
        {
            "path": "${build.id}/resources"
        }
    ],/**
     * File / directory name patttern to ignore when copying to the builds. Must be a
     * valid regular expression.
     */
    "ignore": [
        "(^|/)CVS(/?$|/.*?$)"
    ],/**
     * Directory path to store all previous production builds. Note that the content
     * generated inside this directory must be kept intact for proper generation of
     * deltas between updates.
     */
    "archivePath": "archive/${build.id}",/**
     * The space config object is used by the "sencha app publish" command to publish
     * a version of this application to Sencha Web Application Manager:
     *
     *      "manager": {
     *          // the space id for this application
     *          "id": 12345,
     *
     *          // space host
     *          "host": "https://api.space.sencha.com/json.rpc",
     *
     *          // Either a zip file path or a folder to be zipped
     *          // this example shows how to publish the root folder for all build profiles
     *          "file": "${app.output.base}/../",
     *
     *          // These may be specified here, but are best specified in your user
     *          // ~/.sencha/cmd/sencha.cfg file
     *          "apiKey": "",
     *          "secret": ""
     *      }
     *//**
     * Build Profiles. This object's properties are each a "build profile". You can
     * add as many as you need to produce optimized builds for devices, themes, locales
     * or other criteria. Your "Ext.beforeLoad" hook (see index.html) is responsible for
     * selecting the desired build profile by setting "Ext.manifest" to one of these
     * names.
     *
     *     "builds": {
     *         "classic": {
     *             "toolkit": "classic",
     *             "theme": "theme-neptune"
     *         },
     *
     *         "modern": {
     *             "toolkit": "modern",
     *             "theme": "theme-neptune"
     *         }
     *     }
     *
     */
    "builds": {
        "classic": {
            "toolkit": "classic",
            "theme": "theme-triton",
            "sass": {

            }
        },
        "modern": {
            "toolkit": "modern",
            "theme": "theme-triton",
            "sass": {

            }
        }
    },/**
     * Uniquely generated id for this application, used as prefix for localStorage keys.
     * Normally you should never change this value.
     */
    "id": "*****-****-****"
}
```

Comment: try sencha app build production

Comment: I want to have production build for only classic coz I dont have code for modern theme. How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `app.json`

```
"builds": {
    "classic": {
        "toolkit": "classic",
        "theme": "theme-triton",
        "sass": {

        }
    },
    "modern": {
        "toolkit": "modern",
        "theme": "theme-triton",
        "sass": {

        }
    }
},/**
```

As you can see your app build production is building the code for both types of Ext because you're requiring this, delete "modern" part on "builds", your `app.json` should be like this:

```
 "builds": {
    "classic": {
        "toolkit": "classic",
        "theme": "theme-triton"
    }
},
```

Also, have a look [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?302612-Sencha-CMD-app-build-production-CSS-files-do-not-contain-neutral-theme-entries) for a discussion about that and [here](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/app_json.html) to understand your `app.json`.

After that, you should be able to have your `app.js` compacted and compressed doing a `sencha app build production`